# No RESTAPIs Displayed in AWStoolkit API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to invoke an api from API Gateway but nothing is displayed under APIGATEWAY
[image]

**MY default region** is also **frankfurt**

I have tried to double check using the **cli** but it returns an empty list

[image]

Any idea what can be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: So, what's the problem? If neither the CLI nor the Toolkit display APIs, it is because you do not have any APIs.

Comment: i think it was a misconfusion from my part, i thought that there is already implemented apis that i can customise but apparently not i need to create them. Thanks @AnkushJain